# How can I get my gif to display in the first row and 2 columns of this grid?

Tags: html, css, image, css-grid

I am trying to make cards where the first row and 2 columns are a gif illustrating the card fitting inside a cell with a border. However, there is nothing displaying and the cell just appears empty.

Here is the code I'm using:

```css
.detailsgrid {
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns: 35px 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 200px 40px 1fr 35px;
  border: solid 1px;
}

.detailsimg {
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-row-end: 2;
  grid-column-end: 3;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="detailsgrid">
  <img class="detailsimg" src="https://picsum.photos/100/100" width= 300px>
  </div>
  <div class="detailsname">
    Honing
  </div>
  <div class="detailsdescription">Straightening the blade so it stays sharp (no material is taken off the blade). </div>
  <i class="far fa-clock detailstimeicon"></i>
  <div class="detailstime">
    This is how often you should do it
  </div>
</div>
```

I tried putting 200px so the gif has space to display but ideally I'd like the area to be determined by GIF size.

A picture to illustrate what I'm trying to achieve:

[image: The card design here]

How could I do that?

Comment: Please add a screenshot of the desire design/output you want (No way to guess).

Comment: You cannot have `src` for `div` it should be with `img` tag.

Comment: just added the image to the post! @EzraSiton

Comment: @Manjuboyz You're right.... I've updated and the image appeared. How do I get it to so the grid always take the size of the gif inside?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```css
.detailsgrid {
  display: flex;
  border: solid 1px;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 5px;
  width: 303px;
}

.detailsname {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 50px;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: #1E343A;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 15px;
}

.detailsdescription {
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 50px;
  width: 300px;
  padding: 5px;
}

.detailstime {
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="detailsgrid">
  <div class="details"> <img src="http://placekitten.com/301/301" width=300px>
  </div>

  <div class="detailsname">
    Honing
  </div>

  <div class="detailsdescription">Straightening the blade so it stays sharp (no material is taken off the blade). </div>
  <i class="far fa-clock detailstimeicon"></i>
  <div class="detailstime">
    This is how often you should do it
  </div>
</div>
```

For the second question on the `font-icon`.

```css
.detailsgrid {
  display: flex;
  border: solid 1px;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 5px;
  width: 302px;
}

.detailsname {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 50px;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: #1E343A;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 15px;
}

.detailsdescription {
  display: inline;
  height: 50px;
  width: 300px;
  padding: 5px;
}

.timeBlock {
  display: flex;
  width: 300px;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  height: 50px;
  position: relative;
}

.fa-clock-o {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  padding-top: 7px;
  padding-left: 7px;
}

.detailstime {
  padding-top: 12px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="detailsgrid">
  <div class="details"> <img src="http://placekitten.com/301/301" width=300px>
  </div>

  <div class="detailsname">
    Honing
  </div>

  <div class="detailsdescription">Straightening the blade so it stays sharp (no material is taken off the blade). </div>

  <div class="timeBlock">
    <div class="timeIcon">
      <i class="fa fa-clock-o" aria-hidden="true" style="font-size:36px;background-color:#1E343A;color:white;"></i>

    </div>

    <div class="detailstime">
      This is how often you should do it
    </div>
  </div>



</div>
```

Comment: I'm not sure I can use flex because I'm using code blocks in squarespace. and I would like the tiny icon to be in a different color http://laioliving.knives

Comment: flex is common for all development so no need to worry about it, it is just a property. and about the second question which tiny icon you're talking about? btw I cannot open the link since it is blocked on my ofc laptop!

Comment: If you look back at the original post I added an img with how I would like it to look like. I have a little icon in the left corner it's a white watch on blue background.

Comment: That is font-awesome icon, if you observe your code, that image is not populated in your code as well, mean you may have wrong icon there or something, you may have to find the righ Icon and implement that.

Comment: @Agie971 I have searched for a font icon for you(if this is not the one the change it as you desire and keep the code as is). I have added second snippet as per your requirement hope it works now.

Comment: yes thank you that's i'd like it to be. I can't try it now because squarespace is having issues.